# Zookeeper not able to locate master node in hbase pseudo distributed mode

Tags: hbase, hdfs, distributed-computing

i want to run hbase in pseudo distributed mode, installation is from scratch.
step followed

1. start HBase.
2. Start HBase Master Server
3. Start the region server a
4. Start HBase Shell
5. execute list

Hbase started normally so the hbase shell.
When i checked zookeeper, master as well region all server were up.
For any query on hbase shell prompt, i am getting this error.

> Error - Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null

```
code- configuration -
                hbase-site.xml 
                <configuration>
                   <property>
                      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
                      <value>true</value>
                   </property>
                   //Here you have to set the path where you want HBase to store its files.
                   <property>
                      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
                      <value>hdfs://localhost:8030/hbase</value>
                   </property>
                   <property>
                      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
                      <value>/home/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
                   </property>
                </configuration>
```

Above is my `hbase-site.xml` configuration.
Please help me to understand that what i am missing.

Comment: check path `/hbase/master` in zookeeper, it's abnormal as the error log declaims. maybe you can add to the steps what exact command you execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following properties needs to be added to the hbase xml file in /hbase/conf folder:

```html
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2222</value>
<description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
The port at which the clients will connect.
</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/biadmin/my-local-hbase/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>bivm</value>
</property>
```

Also edit the hbase-env.sh file. Add the correct JAVA_HOME path and uncomment

```html
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

This should resolve the above error!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this property in your hbase-site.xml as well:

```
hbase.zookeeper.quorum
```

Comment: i put <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
      <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.
      </description>
    </property>